# UIWebView reloads content when pushing another view controller

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a view controller added to navigation controller. This controller's view contains UIWebView (webView1).

Now I want to push another view controller with UIWebView (webView2) on top of the navigation controller. I use the

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:animated];
```

Problem is:
Shortly after webView2 starts loading its content, the webView1 reloads its content.

Why webView1 reloads its content? How can I prevent such reloads?

EDIT:

There is absolutely no way these web views can have the same delegate. They reside in objects of different classes.

I can not use `WKWebView` for now.

Comment: Please check with its delegates and confirm that, both webview doesn't have the delegate at same controller.

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour using `WKWebView`? Apple discourages the use of `UIWebView` since iOS 8.